# How to get rounded corners for pop up in kendo ui for dropdown list

Tags: kendo-ui, dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

how to get rounded corners in the popup of the dropdown list?

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
      <p>T-shirt size:</p>
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems"
      [popupSettings]="{
       
       popupClass:'[border-round]'
     }">
      
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </div>
```

where border round is defined in the css as

```
.border-round
{
  border-radius:20px;
 
}
```

i tried this and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In Kendo UI for jQuery, you can override the Kendo CSS class like below:

```
.k-list-container.k-state-border-up {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

If the Kendo UI for Angular uses the same CSS class name, then the above should work.